# Python docx - Force table onto one page if it crosses the page

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm using the `docx` package in Python and I have many small tables which I want to put into the `docx` Word file. However, there are times when a table may cross the page (for example, half the table will be on Page 1 and the other half will be on Page 2). Is there a way to stop this from happening such that the full table will be printed on only one page?

I tried doing things like `table.autofit = False` and `table.allow_autofit = False` but I don't think they're what I need, so if anyone can help me out with it I would greatly appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a pagination property called "keep_together". This is its description in the documentation:

> keep_together causes the entire paragraph to appear on the same page, issuing a page break before the paragraph if it would otherwise be broken across two pages.

I have not tried this in code, but it is how I would format the tables if I was doing it in Word.

This is a link to the documentation:
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html?highlight=break#pagination-properties